# Ошибка при запуске nw.js [0607/131754:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x8b0b1d4600000000, size 0x32 fully unreadable

Tags: javascript

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой при работе с nw.js?
[0607/131754:ERROR:process_info.cc(608)] range at 0x8b0b1d4600000000, size 0x32 fully unreadable

Какие варианты исправить есть?

Comment: Например такие https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4628

Comment: Хм, однако, если запускать по принципу `C:\nw\nw.exe "C:\apps\myapp"` как советуют вот ждесь:  [https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-apps](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-apps) то все работает